# Are there any tools to visualize where the transactions are coming from and going to?

Tags: transactions, wallet, network, legal, tools

We spent some time doing the visualization of the transaction flow between bitcoin wallets https://bitviz.visalyze.com and wanted to know if there are any tools that can not only track, but also visualize where the transactions are coming from and going to?

Answer (score 1):

Blochchain.info also offers a virtuaisation of transactions, called tree chart. It can be view for every transaction over the "View Tree Chart" link.

[image]

Example: https://blockchain.info/tree/59587897

The link you posted seems to be offline, so I'm not sure if it's this sort of visualization you are looking for.

Comment: Looks interesting, thank you. It seems to be little complicated to view the whole flowchart though. Here is the working link I posted https://bitviz.visalyze.com Let me know if this looks any useful to you.

Comment: @mariaviz good to hear it helped you, maybe you can accept the answer ;). I checked out your side, it iss great. I like the visualization-style and it can be rly usefull if you want to do some blockchain forensics. I'm currently on my tab, so I tried how your site works with touch, the zoom-in on touch works as well as moving around but the zoom out is not applied ;). Maybe something that would be nice to add, but only cosmetic. I will try it out further later the day with some of my addresses. Another hint, if you want to get some attention for your side, post it on reddit. Rly like the site.